# Projection onto the column space of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The projection of a vector $v$ onto the column space of A is

$$A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T v$$

If the columns of $A$ are orthogonal, does the projection just become $A^Tv$? I think it should because geometrically you just want to take the dot product with each of the columns of $A$. But how can I show this is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the columns of $A$ are orthonormal, then $A^T A=I$, the identity matrix, so you get the solution as $A A^T v$.

Comment: It is maybe worth to mention that, in this setup, $A^Tv$ are the *coordinates* of the projection in the basis composed of the columns of $A$.